# while running flutter project in VSCode, i found this error

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
[Running] dart "d:\app1\lib\main.dart"
lib/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:app1/main.dart'.
lib/main.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.16.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/E:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^

[Done] exited with code=254 in 10.004 seconds
```

Comment: Firstly do `flutter clean` on terminal, then `flutter pub get`
and then rebuild the app.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh  I tried it but the error still occurs

Comment: Can you include `flutter doctor -v` output

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OVyE4bxHs5myGbbUrLXvNF2fpXCJP2JD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The package version is incompatible with your current dart version. So you could try seeing the version of your material package, and compare that with the dart version you are using. In every case, I recommend updating both, then running:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```